# jQuery accordion not working due to error with sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the following? I know it is something to do with my sources as if I replace them with google apis versions it works fine. But I just can't see what is going wrong.

My folder structure is like:
[image: Folder Structure]

```
<?php
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Collapsible test</title>
    <!--Style Sheet-->
    <Link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></Link>

    <!--js-->
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h3>Test 1</h3>
        <div class="vertical">Test1</div>
        <h3>Test 2</h3>
        <div class="vertical">Test2</div>
        <h3>Test 3</h3>
        <div class="vertical">Test3</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(window).on("resize", function() {
            $('body').width($(window).width());
            $('body').height($(window).height());
        }).resize();

        $(function() {
            $("#container").accordion({
                collapsible: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks like <Link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></Link> should be <Link href="../css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></Link>

Comment: Open the web inspector and check which files are generating a not found error. According to your question it would be the jquery-ui.js file. Tweak the src in your script tags, (src="../)  My guess is that the '../' is not needed because the js folder usually is at the same level as the css folder. Or vice versa, add the '../' to the css link

Comment: jQuery needs to be included before jQuery UI.

Comment: @j08691 If you want to put up an answer I will accept it. If not I will accept KJ Price's as he has now updated and referenced his with your correct answer

Comment: Nah, that's OK. It's not much of an answer in my opinion, and the issue borders on a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is likely referenced in the wrong directory. Try referencing your CSS the same way as your javascript (`../css/`):

```
<link href="../css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></Link>
```

**Edit**: as suggested in another comment by @j08691 your jQuery file needs to be referenced before any other jQuery plugins. The order should be as follows:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: No idea - it wasn't me, I edited that as well. But it was the order of the sources that was causing the main error.

Comment: Ah, I see, part of the problem was that jQuery was referenced after jQuery UI.

Comment: Yeah, true that. I'm going to edit my answer to include that as well. My answer was not wrong. Your css would be out of wack.

Comment: Yeah it was, but hadn't noticed as it's pretty much empty at the moment. Thanks KJ

Comment: Glad I could help @Tom! I should have provided a better answer to begin with.